# Assign variable to $(this).data("whatever") or no?

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

Is there (performance/cpu) effort applied in reading values using jquery data() ?

So... I have several links/buttons, similar to the following

```
<a href='#' class='ui-btn' data-counter='1234'>test</a>
```

When the link is clicked, an event is executed. I need the value of counter more than once during the processing of the event. Should I just read the value from source every time (thus, use `$(this).data("counter")` ) or should I instead do

```
var counter=$(this).data("counter");
```

and reference counter everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely up to you, but work is required every time you call `$(this).data("counter")`. It probably doesn't *matter*, but grabbing it to a local will be shorter to type in the long run and save the odd microsecond.

---

Note that unless you really need the features of [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data), you might want to use [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) instead: `+$(this).attr("data-counter")` (the `+` at the beginning converts from string to number, which `data` does for you with all-digits strings). `data` is **not** an accessor for `data-*` attributes, it's an accessor for jQuery's data cache for that element. The first time you call it on an element, it creates the cache and populates it from all the `data-*` attributes on the element, and then keeps a copy of them as they were at that moment. (And using it as a *setter* doesn't change the attribute, nor does changing the attribute after you've used `data` on the element change `data`'s copy of the values.) `attr` *is* just an accessor for attributes.

Comment: Thanks for this... you've corrected a couple of things - I previously made a question within jquery forum I think and was told to use .data() but the overhead was never explained. Your answer explains the advantages of using attr and data rather well. Kudos to you for this!

Comment: @fiprojects: Happy to help. You'd be amazed how many people think `data("foo")` is just a shorthand for `attr("data-foo")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the value into a variable:

```
var counter=$(this).data("counter");
```

and then:

```
counter++;
...
counter++;
```

and then update your data-attribute again in the end:

```
$(this).data("counter", counter);
```

could be faster.

Comment: Thanks but counter references a record element in a large array and will not be incremented